# Need to store custom user information (many-many relationsips), preferably not as user meta

Tags: database, advanced-custom-fields

I've inherited a site where digital creative types can sign up and register things like software they are capable with (Photoshop, Illustrator, etc....), dates they are available(Using a calendar plugin), genre's they work with, equipment used.

Users can then be searched on these options.

At the moment, the site is set up to use Advanced Custom Fields, but searching this is INCREDIBLY slow, since all options are being stored as an array in user meta - The search is looping through the selected options, and searching the fields like this:

```
...

if (get_query_var("skills")) {
    $skills = get_query_var("skills");
}

 $query = array(
      'role'       => 'editor',
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
      'meta_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND'
      )
  );

if (!empty($skills)) {
    foreach ((array) $skills as $key => $value) {
        $skills_meta = array(
          'key'     => 'skills',
          'value'   => strval($value),
          'compare'   => 'LIKE',
      );
        array_push($query['meta_query'], $skills_meta);
    }
}

... Similar for other options

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($query);
$results = $user_query->get_results();

//- Filter the results by date range if set
if (!empty($results) && isset($start_date)) {
    $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
    $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date));
  // Function loops through all users and checks their availability
  // If they're unavailable within requested range - their removed from the resultset
  $results = array_filter($results, function ($user) use ($start, $end) {
      if ($notavailables = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_availability', $single = true)) {
          $dates = explode(',', $notavailables);
          foreach ($dates as $date) {
              if ($date >= $start && $date <= $end) {
                  return false;
              }
          }

          return true;
      }

      return false;
  });
```

This is obviously incredibly slow, searching in LONGTEXT user_meta.meta_value fields, and another query for each result returned to filter the dates.

I'm not that familiar with wordpress, but am with PHP & MySql in general, so need some guidance.

My idea was to create custom tables that store Skills (ID and skill name), and similar for the other fields, then have a join table that stores user_id & skill id, + similar for others. I'd like to stick with native WP functionality/plugins if possible, so wondering if there is a simpler, but better way.

I've looked at the plugin WP Advanced Search, but it doesn't look like you can search user_meta